# How to show pending changes only for the currently opened solution in Visual Studio 2010 (TFS) and not the complete list of all changes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, view, solution

is there a way to force Visual Studio 2010 to show pending changes only for the currently opened solution? I am working on multiple branches of the same project and changing the same files in most of the branches. It's so painful to check the pending changes by hand every time and double-checking if I've selected the files that I am currently working on...

Comment: Anybody have an idea on how to do this for Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Found solution for TFS 2012 here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17090976/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Open the pending changes window. You can find there a toolbar button that filters on the current solution.

[image]

Comment: Any way to set this as the default?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, on the pending changes view one of the last icons along the top is a "filter by solution" (next to the refresh icon). Click that to reduce the change list to the current solution.

You can see a screenshot of it [here](http://www.dotnetarchitect.co.uk/blog/11-05-04/Visual_Studio_-_Filter_By_Solution.aspx)

Comment: I don't know about other people, but on 2010 Professional, the "filter by solution" button isn't there.

Comment: @HankSchultz: It was added in 2005: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/12/08/filterbysolution.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I see the other answers are quite old.

In 2015 you can do it like this: click on the VisualSVN menu item and then on "Set Working Copy Root..." Then you can browse to the solution folder on disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you bring up the pending changes window. One of the icons is for folder view. This should help with narrowing the changes to a specified directory. (though you will need to deselect the others)

**OR**

There is one option I just remembered for selecting those items. If you open your visual studio command prompt you can use the team foundation tools to auto filter by doing the following.

Example project structure

```
src 
  /Dev
  /Branch1
  /Branch2
```

You can cd into the src directory and use the following command to filter your pending checkins to Branch1

```
tf checkin Branch1 /recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Show Solution Changes, as seen here: (this applies for Visual Studio 2015)

[image]