# Using TFS to manage mockups, other images?

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS server and I often work from two places.  I'd like to have a folder that I just keep my random PSDs, mockups, etc in. Maybe even text file notes, or whatever.

The problem is, when I "Check in" a project, it only includes files that are *included* in the solution.  Is there a simple way to have a folder always included?

For instance right now I just have a "mockups" folder in the root of my Team Project (above any individual project folders), but it's not part of any project or solution (I don't really want to publish a few megs of PSD files every time I publish my project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Solution folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in your Solution and add the files as an existing file.
(or [what is a solution folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374081/what-is-a-solution-folder-in-visual-studio))

Do have the psd and mockups something to do with your code?

If not I wouldn't recommend to add the files to the solution.

I would use the Windows Explorer AddIn from [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).
With it you have the ability to checkin/add/checkout files without Visual Studio, you only need to map a folder to your source control.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can choose on the pending changes window whether you want to have all files checked in from your workspace or from your solution.

See [How to show pending changes only for the currently opened solution in Visual Studio 2010 (TFS) and not the complete list of all changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896899/how-to-show-pending-changes-only-for-the-currently-opened-solution-in-visual-stu/4897964#4897964) for a screenshot.